# Is it wise to use Git to track the currently installed version of a system for multiple customers?

Tags: git, jira, bitbucket, git-extensions, smartgit

We've got a couple of web applications that are manually installed/updated on a few different customers. In order to keep track of what files need to be updated we are using tags on the Git repositories to mark application versions and current version for each of our customers.

As we do updates, the relevant customer(s) tag(s) are deleted and re-created at the appropriate commit to mark it as the current version for said customer.

Lately we've been getting more customers, rendering this process of deletion and creation of tags rather tiresome to perform as well as time consuming.

What would you suggest is a better strategy to keep track of each customer's current system version?

Note: We are also using BitBucket and Jira, if they're at all relevant.

Comment: Do the individual customers have customized versions of the code, or are they simply running different version numbers of the same code base? If it's the latter, then using tags to keep track of which version each customer has been given doesn't seem to me to fit with the intended purpose of tags - it's a deployment issue and has nothing to do with source control. Use tags to denote version numbers, and keep track of which customer has which version somewhere else outside of Git.

Comment: It would be the latter case: the customers are simply running different version numbers of the same code. Sometimes they all are updated together, so a single commit could have a Version Number tag and a tag for each customer. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @JBentley, tags are for your use as a developer. If they help by keping the information of what is running where with the code it describes, it's up to you to use them that way. You might even consider having a separate branch for each customer, if the differences warrant it (but I'd contend that you should work on pruning such, having to manage a bush of dozens of branches isn't fun...)

Comment: @vonbrand It's "up to you" to do whatever you like with any feature of any software. You could for example, store customer billing information in Git tags, or contact information. Just because you "can" do something, doesn't mean it is appropriate. As the OP has discovered, storing deployment information in Git isn't a good idea. There are many reasons for this, and the one the OP has discovered is scalability. Another reason is that he's storing deployment info in a developer tool. This might appear to make sense in a small team where everyone does everything, but...

Comment: .. it ceases to make sense in a larger company structure. Someone working in billing, or technical support, for example, shouldn't need to connect to a Git repo to figure out what version a customer is running. Yet another reason, is that it breaches the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle. By storing customer information in Git, you now have to deal with duplicate records. Any time a customer is added or removed or modified, it has to be done both in Git and in the customer database.

Comment: Yet another reason - you're storing confidential information in a system which you may want to share with people who shouldn't have access to that information. E.g. if the code gets open sourced or farmed out to a freelance coder. Do you really want all your customer information embedded in your source control?

Comment: Indeed, we are a small team and the development team is in charge of updating the customers' system. I think we can agree using tags to keep customer info is not right. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use tags to keep track of customers versions, use then only for tag release versions. Plan the release in Jira and use [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/), it will help you when you move to automatically updates, or even manual.
Also check [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) model, that will help you to think in ways to keep track of features and bugs. That also help when you move to automate builds, code reviews and other agile engineering approachs. Other models for branchs are explained in https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows

After the standardisation of versions in development, the delivery and update with client is a consequence and you can use a variety of process to do that.

Manually you can pull the code and checkout the latest stable revision of the current major version you client use, if you software is a dynamic language software like PHP or Ruby and doesn't need a build process or migrations.

I also recommend some library to manage database migrations and versions as this is a crucial thing if you application use databases (user data is delicated and version control systems do not take care of that alone). If you are on Java land you can use [FlywayDB](http://www.flywaydb.org) or search for alternatives in your environment.

Other cool thing is [docker](https://www.docker.com), is a over kill to your needs, but it is awesome to build containers with all its system dependencies like libraries, especific files, etc,  without the virtualization overhead and with total isolation, it could be used to many things as well to delivery software. I mentioned docker only for cusiosity and high experienced linux engineering.

I hope that helps.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your advice. We do use semantic versioning, and (to some degree) the Git Flow model. Both things are quite helpful in keeping everything in order. Also, we do work mostly using PHP (so far, so good). Database migration/version library is something new, though. I'll definitely check that out.
Just so I'm clear, you suggest handling client updates using git pull; in other words, installing git clients to their servers, right?

Comment: @Ozzyberto Yes one suggestion is to install git on they servers and pull the master branch (supposing your master branch is the stable one)

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help.